# HandlerSocket giving error 167 - what does it mean?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I have a PHP based multi-threaded application that I'm try to get working with the HandlerSocket plugin for MySql.

When running as a single process it works fine. When I start multi threading it, I get an error when inserting - it just says "167".

I have occasionally gotten "121" - which I've figured out means duplicate key error.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else coming across this error with handler socket - it was caused by having more concurrent write processes than the number of threads dealing with handler socket writes in mysql.

Looks like there is a bug with race conditions within handler socket for getting auto increment values. Either up the number of write threads in my.conf, have less concurrent writes (maybe implement your own locking/connection pool), or wait for the bug to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently...

```
MySQL error code 167: Failed to set row auto increment value
```